# Where do browsers save/store auto fill data

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete, passwords, browser-security

where do browsers store passwords and username when we opt for remember password. Is it always cookies or some other encrypted file.Also where is the data filled by auto complete functionality of browsers come from. It doesn't seem to come from cookies as same auto-complete info sometimes appears in fields of websites other than those it was previously filled in. Is it possible to retrieve data from browser itself(sensitive as well as the general one)?

Comment: It stores the data where you define it in the settings...

Answer (score 0):

Password that are autocompleted by the browser are NOT saved in cookies.

Some old documentation for firefox:

- http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/904650

But why do you even want to do that ? There is no way for example in javascript to read the passwords from the users system.

Answer (score 0):

> where do browsers store passwords and username when we opt for remember password.

Depends on the browser

> Is it always cookies or some other encrypted file.

If it is the browser feature, then it will never be a cookie.

If it is a website feature, then it will depend on the website (but is likely to be a cookie)

> Also where is the data filled by auto complete functionality of browsers come from.

Depends on the browser

> Is it possible to retrieve data from browser itself(sensitive as well as the general one)?

Not if you are Joe Arbitrary Website, that would be a disturbing security hole.

Comment: I understand your concerns. I am only preparing myself for preventing something bad happen to me. I usually autosave my password on my PC and want to be sure that there is ABSOLUTELY NO WAY that ANYBODY can get my credentials or preferences

Comment: @VaibhavSingla — So you have a question about the security of a feature of some software you are using? That isn't a programming problem. You should have asked this on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably worried about security as in using auto fill with important information having cookies would give the user more control over information given out by the user. I'm sure the way it's set up now it's protected under contractual law.