# Jquery: retrieve and print browser's autofill data into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, browser, autofill

Is there any way to retrieve the user's autofill data (e.g. email, phoning, etc stored in browser) and automatically print each value into corresponding textfields? I guess the answer here is No as regards to privacy concerns so if how about:

Would it be possible to add a button at the top of the form which (if clicked) prints the values from browser's autofill data into the corresponding fields? Hence, same as above but on demand from the user (same functionality as the browser autofill button that can be added to e.g. Safari's toolbar.)

We would like to do this in order to simplify for the user when filling out our registration form.

Comment: You could wait until browser autofilled all fields and then just iterate through all the fields and grab the values.

Comment: you would need to store the data and populate it for user. You can't access user autofill stored by browser

Comment: And there's no way to call the "populate fields from browser autofill" via a button or similar?

Comment: Whether you call it by a button or diectly is irrelevant (from the browser's perspective). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423734/is-there-any-way-to-access-browser-form-field-suggestions-from-javascript